transit visa for Dominican traveling to Lima through Panama
I'm a US citizen. I visit my wife, who is a Dominican citizen living in DR. We are waiting for her spouse visa. We want to visit Lima next year during my visit to DR. Will she need a transit visa for a layover in Panama?

According to Timatic, for a Dominican citizen traveling from the DR to Peru with a transit in Panama:

TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit
area of the airport and have documents required for the next
destination.

If the booked flight is a single ticket meeting these requirements, your wife should not need a transit visa.
